# Add Currency Symbol to Splunk Query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have a column in splunk that I want to use to show totals. I would like for the dollar sign ($) to appear before the numbers in the totals column.

Here's my query:

```
index=prd_aws_billing (source="/*2017-12.csv") LinkedAccountId="123456678" ProductName="Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud" | stats sum(UnBlendedCost) AS Cost by ResourceId,UsageType,user_Name,user_Engagement
```

How do I get the numbers in the UnBlendedCost column to appear with a dollar sign in front of them?

Answer (score 0):

Here you changed the field from "unBlendedCost" to "sum(unBlendedCost)", so you should add an alias such as `sum(unBlendedCost) AS unBlendedCost` and it should work.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get a $ sign to appear before the numbers in the UnBlendedCost column. Sorry if I didn't explain that well. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to turn the number to a string then concatenate the $ symbol on it like this

`| fieldformat cost="$".tostring(Cost)`